# Angular2 Two-Way-Binding stopped working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having trouble updating my view. In ngOnInit I am resolving a promise. If it cannot do the HTTP request (i.e. there is no internet) then the catch should look into local storage to find the user and display the information in the view.

**Important: It just doesn't work when I redirect the user from the login page to the home page using .navigate. If I reload the component once in home page it does work.**

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code in the home page component:

```
   ngOnInit() {

 this.mySession.isLoggedIn()
 // make request to server via HTTP

 .then( userInfo => {
   // if request successful do:
   this.user = userInfo;
   this.user2 = userInfo;

   if(this.user.searchbar === false) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', false);
   } else if(this.user.searchbar) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', true);
   }
 })

 // if request via HTTP fails do:
 .catch(() => {
   // find user in Local Storage and set it equal to this.user;
   this.getLocalUser();
   console.log('catch within home component');
 });

}

 getLocalUser() {
 chrome.storage.sync.get(this.signupInfo,(response) => {
   this.user = {};

   this.user = response;
   this.user2 = response;

   console.log('this.user: ');
   console.log(this.user);

   if(this.user.searchbar === false) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', false);
   } else if(this.user.searchbar) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', true);
   }
 });
}
```

This is my HTML-Template within the home page component:

```
<h4>
  <div id="firstGreeting" class="greeting">Good Day, {{ user.firstName }}.</div>
  <span class="highlight disappear">How is your day going?</span>
  <div class="highlight second">Do you mind telling why?</div> <br>
  <span class="forMonth"> - {{ stringMonth }} - </span>
</h4>
```

This is the code within the login component that redirects to from the login to the home page:

```
signup() {
const thePromise = this.mySession.signUp(this.signupInfo);

thePromise.then(userInfo => {
  console.log('User was saved in the server');
  // Save user to Local Storage using Chrome API

  chrome.storage.sync.set(this.signupInfo, () => {
    // Notify that we saved.
    console.log('User was saved locally in the pc');

    this.myNavigator.navigate(['home']);
    return;
  });
});

thePromise.catch((err) => {
  this.error = err;
  console.log(this.error)
});
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should consider abstracting the offline code into your `mySession` service so that it returns the user info from either the HTTP request or the offline cache so that it is invisible to your component. That way you're not repeating your code in the `getLocalUser()` function.

Comment: For the question, it's not clear what the relationship between your `ngOnInit` function and the `signup` function is, nor where the `ngOnInit` is. On the login page? On the home page?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I edited my answer to be more explicit! And thank you for the feedback. I am currently refactoring my code and will do as you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You code has a reference issue. Here 'this' in function(response) is a reference of function(response). You may use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or let that = this outside function and use that inside function.

```
getLocalUser() {
 chrome.storage.sync.get(this.signupInfo, (response) => {
   this.user = {};

   this.user = response;
   this.user2 = response;

   console.log('this.user: ');
   console.log(this.user);

   if(this.user.searchbar === false) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', false);
   } else if(this.user.searchbar) {
     $('#searchbar').prop('checked', true);
   }
});
```

If this does not work, please post your template.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I actually tried the arrow function and it did not work. I added some extra information that might be useful. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: What is 'myNavigator'? And can you show your routing settings?